Ошибка AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__mro__'
database.py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, DeclarativeBase




#class DataBase:
    #def __init__(self,db_url):
        #self.engine = create_engine(db_url)
        #self.SessionLocal = sessionmaker


SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./user_date.db"
    
engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL,
        connect_args={"check_same_thread": False})

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autoflush=False , bind=engine)
db = SessionLocal()



class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass



Models.py
from fastapi import File
from database import Base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, mapped_column



class ModelUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id : Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, index=True)
    name : Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    lastname : Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    age: Mapped[int] = mapped_column()
    photo: Mapped[File] = mapped_column()





main.py

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from database import engine, SessionLocal, Base
from models import ModelUser
from sqlalchemy.orm import  Session


Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)


app = FastAPI()

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


class ModelUserDTO(BaseModel):
    name : str = Field(min_length=11)
    lastname: str = Field(min_length= 1, max_length=25)
    age : int
    photo: bytes




@app.post("/useradd/", tags=["Добавление пользователя в БД"])
# Создание Пользователя 
async def CreateUser(user: ModelUserDTO, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = ModelUser()
    db_user.name = user.name
    db_user.lastname = user.lastname
    db_user.age = user.age
    db_user.photo = user.photo
    
    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()

    return db_user

@app.get("/allusers/")
async def AllGetUsers(db: Session = Depends()):
    pass


AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'mro'
Просчитался но где , Напишите где я ошибся и как это исправить
Ошибка:
Process SpawnProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 314, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\_subprocess.py", line 78, in subprocess_started
    target(sockets=sockets)
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 62, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 194, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 685, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\server.py", line 69, in serve
    config.load()
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\config.py", line 458, in load
    self.loaded_app = import_from_string(self.app)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\importer.py", 
line 21, in import_from_string
    module = importlib.import_module(module_str)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in 
import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "G:\Builds\ProjectApiPython\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from models import UserModel
  File "G:\Builds\ProjectApiPython\models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class ModelUser(Base):
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_api.py", line 836, in __init_subclass__
    _as_declarative(cls._sa_registry, cls, cls.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_base.py", line 244, in _as_declarative
    return _MapperConfig.setup_mapping(registry, cls, dict_, None, {})
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_base.py", line 325, in setup_mapping
    return _ClassScanMapperConfig(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_base.py", line 571, in __init__
    self._extract_mappable_attributes()
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_base.py", line 1541, in _extract_mappable_attributes
    value.declarative_scan(
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\properties.py", line 709, in declarative_scan
    self._init_column_for_annotation(
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\properties.py", line 866, in _init_column_for_annotation
    new_sqltype = registry._resolve_type(check_type)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lamantine\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\decl_api.py", line 1259, in _resolve_type
    search = ((pt, pt) for pt in python_type_type.__mro__)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '__mro__'




Для начала ошибка должна быть представлена в вопросе в виде полного стек-трейса. По обрывкам ошибок не гадаем.

Поправил пост!!

Для начала я бы попробовал откатить питон на какую-то более старую версию. Вы уверены, что все модули, которые вы поставили и используете совместимы с питоном 3.12?
